# Java bounded type parameters

Tags: java, generics, types

1.I thought that Interfaces in Java don't have implementations, so how can I use my compareTo() here?

2.As far as I knew the *extends* keyword can add new methods to an interface in order to be implemented later.
So I don't understand what/how am I exactly extending right here ?

Thanks

```
public class Compare {

    // simple comparison operator < > ... works only on primitives
    // that's why we need the Comparable
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
        int count = 0;

        for (T e : anArray)
            if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
                ++count;

        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Interfaces in Java don't have implementations, but you **can't** create an instance of an interface. (Try it - what happens when you include `new List()` in your code?) You can **only** create an instance of a class implementing that interface, and the class is required to implement the interface's methods.
2. In this case, you're not extending anything at all yourself. You just indicate 'this method can only be used for classes `T` which extend/implement the `Comparable<T>` interface'.

Comment: but my class *Compare* does not implement/extend the Comparable<T> interface and I still can call this method(countGreaterThan).

Comment: Yes, because it is important that 'T' implements the interface, not Compare itself. That would only be important when you try to call something like `Compare.countGreaterThan(arrayOfCompares, instanceOfCompare)`.

Comment: so in a case of an Array with Integers[] the function CompareTo has already been implemented by Java developers  right ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually from Java 8 onwards, Interfaces *can* have (default, partial) implementation, but that's an aside. The confusing thing here is that the keyword `extends` has two usages:

1. extending the *functionality* of classes and, as you correctly say, by analogy the Interface class hierarchies.
2. For Generic classes, [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) are used for defining the *bounds* of a type parameter, e.g. `List<T extends Comparable>`. Using the same key word was a decision made when they introduced this, presumably to emphasise how the kind of class that is suitable for this Generic `T` *would itself have to extend* `Comparable` (for example). As classes and interfaces in Java share the same hierarchies, it doesn't really matter which you use here (though interfaces are advisable).